# Ayuda con la hora no logro mostrar am o pm en mi base de datos

Tags: php, android, mysql

**Tengo este  código en android studio  para  mostrar la  hora en un EdiText.**

```
//MOSTRAMOS HORA
   Thread t = new Thread()
   {
       @Override
       public  void run()
       {
           try{
               while(!isRestricted()){
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           hora=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethora);
                           long date=System.currentTimeMillis();
                           java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
                           String dateString=sdf.format(date);
                           hora.setText(dateString);
                       }
                   });
               }
           }catch (InterruptedException e)
           {}
       }
   };
   t.start();
```

**Hasta aquí  todo  bien,me muestra  la hora  en el EditText  poniendome 
am  o pm**

Ahora intento guardar  la  hora en mi base de datos de  esta  manera.

```
    hora.getText().toString()
```

si me  lo guarda  pero no me  muestra  en mi base de  datos  si es am o pm .

**Esta es  la estructura de mi base de  datos.**

```
  CREATE TABLE Tiempo (

  `Fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` time DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Agrego mi código  PHP**

```
<?php  

       require('conexion.php');

        $Fecha=$_POST['Fecha'];
        $hora=$_POST['hora'];

        // Sentencia 
        $comando = "INSERT INTO Tiempo ( ".
            " Fecha," .
            " hora)" .
            " VALUES( ?,?)";

        // Preparar la sentencia
        $sentencia =$conn->prepare($comando);

         $sentencia->execute(
            Array{
                $Fecha,
                $hora
            )
        );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes guardar la hora en la base de datos asi:

```
hora.getText().toString("hh:mm:ss a");
```

o bien puedes usar el formato de 24 horas para guardarla y poder convertirla al momento de obtenerla sin problemas:

```
hora.getText().toString("HH:mm:ss");
```